# How do you avoid small values in d3 interpolate?

Tags: d3.js

According to the d3 docs:

When interpolating to or from zero, some interpolated values may be very small. JavaScript formats small numbers in exponential notation, which unfortunately is not supported by CSS. For example, when transitioning opacity to fade in or out, the number 0.0000001 is converted to the string "1e-7" and then ignored, giving the default value of 1! To avoid distracting flicker, start or end the transition at 1e-6 rather than 0; this is the smallest value not formatted in exponential notation.

This is giving me a problem with a histogram which has some very low frequencies. The rectangle height is interpolated as a scientific number which throws an error. I've tried the following:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(freq)
    .filter(function(d) {return d.freq>0.005})
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.freq); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.freq) })
```

This avoids the end value being zero - but how do I filter out those elements where the initial value may be close to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing when you're creating the bars, i.e.

```
svg.selectAll("rect").data(freq).filter(...)
   .enter().append("rect");
```

At this point, it would actually make sense to prefilter your data before passing it to D3 at all, i.e. use something like `var filteredData = data.filter(...)` and use `filteredData`.